# Exclude maven dependencies from springboot

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

I have a springboot project which adds all the dependent jars to **lib** folder.
How I can avoid this?

I tried this and it is not working

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <!-- <excludeScope>compile</excludeScope>
                        <excludeArtifactIds>*</excludeArtifactIds>
                        <excludeGroupIds>*.*</excludeGroupIds> -->
        <exclude>
            <groupId>*.*</groupId>
            <artifactId>*</artifactId>
        </exclude>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I don't want to put dependencies as **provided**

Any other solutions?

Comment: It doesn't work also because from [official documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.3.3.RELEASE/maven-plugin/repackage-mojo.html) it doesn't support regex or wildcards, it expects an exact match

Comment: Thanks Matteo for the reply. Is there any other way, other than putting the exact matches?

Comment: why don't you want the `provided` deps exactly?

Comment: there are too many dependencies and I have to put **provided** in all of them. Thought there might be better ways.

Comment: @RavindraDevadiga well, with any text editor that would be rather easy, just replace </dependency> by <scope>provided</scope></dependency> and you would automatically do the trick in one shot ;-) (checking no side effects though while doing it)

Comment: If you have too many dependencies that shouldn't be used when your app runs, then there is a problem in your build. Fixing your pom.xml is the way to go.

Answer (score 4):

You can exclude by specifying which dependencies you don't need in your pom.
Something like below.

Here I don't need embeded tomcat provided by boot. So we can exclude it using below tags:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
<exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
</exclusions>
```

Comment: How can we exclude all dependencies of a group?

Lets say I want to exclude all dependencies belonging to this group id

 <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>

Comment: @hemanto you can use excludeGroupIds for that